# Simple FullCalendar doesn't render events in FireFox 3.6.13

Tags: fullcalendar

http://sptutil.s3.amazonaws.com/js/fullcalendar/bugs/firefox-nodisplay.html

Two events, defined as arrays, with a title, start in ISO8601 date format, and an allDay: false directive. Renders events fine in Chrome, but FF3/4 render the calendar but not the events.

I'm not getting errors in FireBug, and I'm a bit embarrassed that this is going to be something ridiculously simple that I merely overlooked.

Comment: Apparently doesn't render in IE8 either. This makes me think it's a syntax error, but neither Firebug nor the IE8 developer tools are giving me a hint yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
start: "2011-01-23T16:25:00Z"
```

(Jan is 01, not 1)

Comment: Thank you!! This was killing me. For reference, the ToString format in C# that works for all browsers is: `yyyy'-'MM'-'ddTHH':'mm':'ss'Z'`

Comment: @goldenratio, the `Z` at the end could cause unintended side-effects because it might recast the time of the appointment to GMT and that could mess up all-day events (as it did for me).